# Sort Documents from different types

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a little problem with my sorting of the menue.

I tried everything… Sort by Name, Sort by ID, Sort by creation,.. But the different types never mixed up.

I would like a sorting like 0. .. 1. .. 2. .. 3. ..

Does anybody know why the sorting didnt work or has an idea how to realize the menue?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you have folders and items, they don't sort as one set.

Comment: Typical poor design by Microsoft. No reason for it other than bad design.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Folder are always displayed first in order of sort by columns and then files. Same is case in Windows explorer.  So basically Sort by column works individually for folder and files. Folders will be displayed first.

Found a workaround but not sure if it will work for you or not

Here is a workaround, you can have a try if it can meet your demand.

There is a feature called "Group by" and you can find it when you create or modify a view. Here you can make the files and folders group by Title that items have same title would be included to a same group.

Now you can make the items sort by Title and they will display as groups.

Ref link - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/addda874-8ee6-460d-be5f-8e9016916104/list-view-sort-folders-and-files-together?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Answer (score 1):

First - thanks for your answers! 
I found also a good uncomplicated way.

I just sort my first column by Icon - there are just explorer and folder icons, so this shouldnt be a problem to sort.
Sort in descending order and click on "Sort only by specified criteria (folders may not appear before items). "

[image]

Now it is working.[image]

Comment: This should be the answer. Even easier, you can just click on the "Sort only by specified criteria (folders may not appear before items)." and it should ignore the folder vs items sort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is by design.
As a workaround, I recommend that you can create a new column and then fill in the order you want with different items.
[image]